# XeTeX fails with undefined control sequence in texlive 2012/dev

Tags: xetex, errors, xparse

I'm using XeTeX, and I'm trying to compile a document using the following command:

```
xelatex mydoc.tex
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ExplFileName

l.57 ...e}{\ExplFileVersion}{\ExplFileDescription}
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't even have `\usepackage{xparse}`, probably some other package loads it.

My XeTeX version is: `XeTeX 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2012/dev)`

Any Ideas how to fix this?

I'm Using http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/texlive/packages.fc14/texlive-release.noarch.rpm in Fedora 14, if that is of any help.

Comment: 1. In the log file you can clearly see what other package is loading the xparse package. 2. Have you already tried updating your TL2011 with "sudo tlmgr update --all"?

Comment: Unfortunately, we aren't psychic. As you rightly guess, some other package is probably loading `xparse` but without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), we have no way of knowing what.

Comment: He's not using TL 2011, but 2012/dev! Anyway, `fontspec` loads `xparse`.

Comment: @frabjous: Oh yes, you are right, haven't seen this. The title of this question is misleading because it states "texlive 2011".

Comment: @Axel: Well, `fontspec` uses it. The `tlmgr` tool is not available.

Comment: Make sure that the l3kernel package is up-to-date.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, those packages are all up to date... Don't know what else could be done...

Comment: What do you mean by "as far as I'm concerned". Did you compare the versions mentioned in the log and the current on CTAN? Which version of `l3bootstrap` is your document using?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: How can I find that out? Also, I added the repo where I got my texlive release from.

Comment: Add `\lisftiles` to the beginning of the code, and post the file list it puts in the log file here.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using TL2012/dev instead of the stable (and recently released) TL2011? Running the in-development version at such an early stage practically ensures that things are going to break.

Comment: @polemon: Don't use a development version if you are not able to find a log file, to check the version of a package you are using, to check a version on CTAN or to install a package manually from CTAN. Development versions are for people with at least a bit knowledges on the technical background.

Comment: @polemon: I strongly recommend switching to TL2011, too.

Comment: OK, I'll see if I can get the repos in order to downgrade to TL2011.

Comment: OK, I downgraded to TL2011, it all works now. Ulrike, if you want an accepted answer, just add one, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Ulrike: Could you please add an answer. (polemon: Users only get notified by you comments if you [put an @ in front of their name](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets-n) or they are the owner of a question/answer.)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 3):

Try removing TeX Live's `expl3`.  It seems that `expl3` is now known as `l3kernel` but jnovy's repository still includes both and causes some confusion.